# Check the record of first and last element of checkbox checked whether this record is already exists or not when click on save button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am making time table for leatures

Where user select a **session,batch,module,instructor,weekday,start time, end time and room** when click on save button then that row of table will be checked from database. if user add more table row then click on add more anchor tag

Here is the complete code of html

```
 <div class="row">
     <form class="col s12" action="insert_timetable.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frm1" id="frm1">
        <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
          <div class="card-panel">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="input-field col s2">
                    <label>
                    Session
                    </label>
                      <select id="sessionid" data-rel="chosen" name="sessionid" class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">2018</option>
                        </select>

                  </div>
               </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="card-panel">
               <div class="row">
               <table class="striped display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="myTable">
                  <tbody>
                  <?php for($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++ ){?>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="chk<?php echo $i;?>" name="chk[]" value="<?php echo $i;?>"/>
                    <tr id="row<?php echo $i?>">
                        <td class="input-field col s2">
                    <label>
                     Batch
                     </label>
                        <select id="batchid<?php echo $i?>" data-rel="chosen " name="batchid<?php echo $i?>" class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">Batch01</option>
                        <option value="2">Batch02</option>
                        <option value="3">Batch03</option>
                        </select>

                        </td>
                        <td class="input-field col s2">
                    <label>
                    Module
                    </label>
                        <select id="moduleid<?php echo $i?>" data-rel="chosen" name="moduleid<?php echo $i?>" class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">Module01</option>
                        <option value="2">Module02</option>
                        <option value="3">Module03</option>
                        </select>

                  </td>
                        <td class="input-field col s2">
                    <label>
                    Instructor
                    </label>
                        <select id="instructorid<?php echo $i;?>" data-rel="chosen" name="instructorid<?php echo $i;?>" class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">Asif</option>
                        <option value="2">Usman</option>
                        <option value="3">Ali</option>
                        </select>

                  </td>     
                        <td class="input-field col s2">
                    <label>
                    Week Days
                    </label>
                    <select id="week_days<?php echo $i;?>" data-rel="chosen" name="week_days<?php echo $i;?>[]" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">Monday</option>
                    <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
                    <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
                    <option value="4">Thursday</option>
                    <option value="5">Friday</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                        <td class="input-field col s1">
                    <label>
                    Start Time
                    </label>
                    <input id="class_strt<?php echo $i;?>" class="timepicker" type="time" name="class_strt<?php echo $i;?>">
                  </td>
                        <td class="input-field col s1">
                    <label>
                    End Time
                    </label>
                    <input id="class_end<?php echo $i;?>" class="timepicker" type="time" name="class_end<?php echo $i;?>">
                  </td>
                        <td class="input-field col s1">
                    <label>
                     Duration
                     </label>
                        <input id="duration_id<?php echo $i;?>" type="text" name="duration_id<?php echo $i;?>">

                  </td>
                        <td class="input-field col s1">
                    <label>
                    Room
                    </label>
                    <select id="room<?php echo $i;?>" data-rel="chosen" name="room<?php echo $i;?>" class="browser-default">
                        <option value="1">Room01</option>
                        <option value="2">Room02</option>
                        <option value="3">Room03</option>
                        </select>
                  </td>
          <td id="btn<?php echo $i?>"><a data-remove-id="<?php echo $i?>" class="btn_remove  right hidden" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="../../assets/images/icons/close.png" width="23px" title="Remove"/></a></td>
                    </tr>

  <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <a id="more_btn" class="right" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="../../assets/images/icons/add-icon.ico" width="23px" title="Add More"/></a>

               </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="button" id="submit_btn">Save
                        <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
            </div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

I make a scenaior of workflow how many checkboxes are checked that record are saved into database. When click on save button then **First** and **Last** element of checkbox checked that records check from database whether this record is aleady exists or not

Here Is the code of script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var j=1;
 var i=1;
 if(j==1){
    var chk = document.getElementById("chk1").value;
    $("#chk"+chk).attr('checked', true);

    $('#class_end'+j).on('change',function() 
    {
        var start_time = $('#class_strt'+j).val();
        var end_time = $('#class_end'+j).val();
        var diff = ( new Date("1970-1-1 " + end_time) - new Date("1970-1-1 " + start_time) ) / 1000 / 60;
        var hour = parseInt(diff/60);
        var minutes  = diff%60;
        if(minutes<10){
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
            }
        $('#duration_id'+j).val(hour + ":" + minutes);

    });

}

for (i; i <= 5; i++) {

if(i==1){
    $('#row'+i).show();
    $('#btn'+i).hide();
}else{
    $('#row'+i).hide();
    $('#btn'+i).show();
}
}


$('#more_btn').click(function() {
j++;
var u = j-1;

var batchid = $('#batchid'+u).val();
var moduleid = $('#moduleid'+u).val();
var sessionid = $('#sessionid').val();
var instructorid = $('#instructorid'+u).val();
var prev_start_time = $('#class_strt'+u).val();
var prev_end_time = $('#class_end'+u).val();
var duration_id = $('#duration_id'+u).val();
var prev_room = $('#room'+u).val();
var prev_weekdays = $('#week_days'+u).val();
//alert(prev_weekdays); 
/*var weekDay_field = prev_weekdays.toString().split(",");
        var weekDay1 = weekDay_field[0];
        var weekDay2 = weekDay_field[1];
        var weekDay3 = weekDay_field[2];
        var weekDay4 = weekDay_field[3];
        var weekDay5 = weekDay_field[4];*/

//Previous Start Time Split     
var prev_s_t = prev_start_time.split(':');
var pst1 = prev_s_t[0];
var pst2 = prev_s_t[1];

//Previous End Time Split       
var prev_end_t = prev_end_time.split(':');
var pet1 = prev_end_t[0];
var pet2 = prev_end_t[1];
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check_timetable.php",
    data: {batch: batchid, session: sessionid, module: moduleid, instructor: instructorid, startTime: prev_start_time, endTime:prev_end_time,duration:duration_id, weekday: prev_weekdays, room: prev_room},
    success: function(result) {
        var value = $.trim(result);
        //alert(value);
        //prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", value);
        if (value == "1"){
            alert('TimeTable Found');
            $('#class_strt'+u).val('');
            $('#class_end'+u).val('');
        } else{ 
            var chk = document.getElementById("chk"+j).value;
            $("#chk"+chk).attr('checked', true);
            $('#row'+j).show();
        }      
    },

}); 

$('#class_end'+j).on('change',function() 
    {   
        var curr_weekdays = $('#week_days'+j).val();
        //alert(curr_weekdays);
        /*var curr_weekday_fields = curr_weekdays.toString().split(",");
        var curr_weekDay1 = curr_weekday_fields[0];
        var curr_weekDay2 = curr_weekday_fields[1];
        var curr_weekDay3 = curr_weekday_fields[2];
        var curr_weekDay4 = curr_weekday_fields[3];
        var curr_weekDay5 = curr_weekday_fields[4];*/

        var start_time = $('#class_strt'+j).val();
        var end_time = $('#class_end'+j).val();
        var diff = ( new Date("1970-1-1 " + end_time) - new Date("1970-1-1 " + start_time) ) / 1000 / 60;
        var hour = parseInt(diff/60);
        var minutes  = diff%60;
        if(minutes<10){
            minutes = "0" + minutes;    
            }
        $('#duration_id'+j).val(hour + ":" + minutes);

        //Start Time Split 
        var s_t = start_time.split(':');
        var st1 = s_t[0];
        var st2 = s_t[1];
        //End Time split
        var e_t = end_time.split(':');
        var et1 = e_t[0];
        var et2 = e_t[1];

        if(curr_weekdays==prev_weekdays && st1 == pet1 && st2 == pet2){
            $('#class_strt'+j).val('');
            $('#class_end'+j).val('');
            alert("Please add 5 minutes break in Start Time");
        }

        if(st1 == pst1 && st2 >= pst2 && et1 <= pet1 && et2 >= pet2 && curr_weekdays==prev_weekdays) {
            $('#class_strt'+j).val('');
            $('#class_end'+j).val('');
         var op = document.getElementById("room"+j);
         for (var x = 0; x < op.length; x++) {
            if(op.options[x].value == prev_room ) {
                op.options[x].disabled = true;
            }
            }
        } else {
            var op = document.getElementById("room"+j);
         for (var x = 0; x < op.length; x++) {
            if(op.options[x].value == prev_room ) {
                op.options[x].disabled = false;
            }
            }
        }       
    });
    });

    $('#myTable').on('click','.btn_remove',function(){ 
    var check = confirm("Are you sure delete this row?");
    if (check == true) {
        var button_id = $(this).data("remove-id");  
        $('#row'+button_id+'').remove(); 
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
     });
   });
</script>
```

Issue is that how to check only first and last element of checkbox checked. I am checking this way, when user selecting record of first row then click on save button this record will be checked from database and when user selecting record of more than row then click on save button this record will be checked from database.

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
var chkValue = $('[name="chk[]"]:checkbox:checked:visible:first').val();
//var chkValue1 = $('[name="chk[]"]:checkbox:checked:visible:last').val();
//var chkLength = $('[name="chk[]"]:checked').length;
        var batchid = $('#batchid'+chkValue).val();
        var moduleid = $('#moduleid'+chkValue).val();
        var sessionid = $('#sessionid').val();
        var instructorid = $('#instructorid'+chkValue).val();
        var prev_start_time = $('#class_strt'+chkValue).val();
        var prev_end_time = $('#class_end'+chkValue).val();
        var duration_id = $('#duration_id'+chkValue).val();
        var prev_room = $('#room'+chkValue).val();
        var prev_weekdays = $('#week_days'+chkValue).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "check_multi_timetable.php",
                data: {batch: batchid, session: sessionid, module: moduleid, instructor: instructorid, startTime: prev_start_time, endTime:prev_end_time,duration:duration_id, weekday: prev_weekdays, room: prev_room},
                success: function(result) {
                var value = $.trim(result);
                    if (value == "1"){
                        alert('TimeTable Already Exist');
                } else{ 
                        alert("enter");
                    //document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
        }      
    },

}); 
var chkValue1 = $('[name="chk[]"]:checkbox:checked:visible:last').val();
//var chkLength = $('[name="chk[]"]:checked').length;
        var batchid = $('#batchid'+chkValue1).val();
        var moduleid = $('#moduleid'+chkValue1).val();
        var sessionid = $('#sessionid').val();
        var instructorid = $('#instructorid'+chkValue1).val();
        var prev_start_time = $('#class_strt'+chkValue1).val();
        var prev_end_time = $('#class_end'+chkValue1).val();
        var duration_id = $('#duration_id'+chkValue1).val();
        var prev_room = $('#room'+chkValue1).val();
        var prev_weekdays = $('#week_days'+chkValue1).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "check_multi_timetable.php",
                data: {batch: batchid, session: sessionid, module: moduleid, instructor: instructorid, startTime: prev_start_time, endTime:prev_end_time,duration:duration_id, weekday: prev_weekdays, room: prev_room},
                success: function(result) {
                var value = $.trim(result);
                    if (value == "1"){
                        alert('TimeTable Already Exist');
                } else{ 
                        alert("enter");
                    //document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
        }      
    },

}); 
});
```

Suppose

**1)** User enter a page for creating a time table and user selecting record of first row then click on save button then this record of first row will be checked from database.

**2)** User enter a page for creating a time table and user selecting record of first row and second row then click on save button then this record of first row and second row will be checked from database because of first and last element of checkbox checked.

**3)** User enter a page for creating a time table and user selecting record of first row and second row and third row then click on save button then this record of first row and third row will be checked from database because of first and last element of checkbox checked.

**Problem**

user select record in first table row then click on save button its checking if record found in db then stop execution and user select record more than one table row then click on save button its checking if first row record is not found and second row record also not found and third table row record is found but its still form submit

Comment: Unclear what your actual problem or question is here.

Comment: check my last 3 suppose points

Comment: I can’t even tell if those are supposed to be the problem description (i.e., what goes wrong), or simply a wish list of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: problem is that user select record in first table row then click on save button its checking if record found in db then stop execution and user select record more than one table row then click on save button its checking if first row record is not found and second row record also not found and third table row record is found but its still form submit